# Unable to write unit test for Spring @Scheduler

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, spring-scheduled, shedlock

I have implemented a scheduler with shedlock in my current spring project as follows:

```
  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * *")
  @SchedulerLock(name = "syncData",
      lockAtMostFor = "${shedlock.myScheduler.lockAtMostFor}",
      lockAtLeastFor = "${shedlock.myScheduler.lockAtLeastFor}")
  public void syncSAData() {
    //To assert that the lock is held
    LockAssert.assertLocked();
    ...
  }
```

Now I would like to write unit test for this function. Here the problem I am facing is: I am unable to mock first statement: `LockAssert.assertLocked()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick `LockAssert.TestHelper.makeAllAssertsPass(true);`

Just add it at the beginning of the test method.

Docs: https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#lock-assert